# How to install filedialog package?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I Can't able install filedialog package in python3 it shows already requirement satisfied. The package is installed but not working. Can anyone help me to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Tkinter's askopenfilenames. This is very similar to FileDialog, but with the Tkinter module.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import askopenfilenames
root = tkinter.Tk().withdraw()

files = askopenfilenames() #This is the FileDialog window
```